# Python Thread running asynchronously

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am trying to run the below code expecting it to run asynchronously.

```
import threading
import time


def mock_app(widgets=None, filters=None):
    print('Mock app called')
    task = threading.Thread(target=mock_app_handler(), args=())
    task.start()
    print('Thread spawned')
    return "success"


def mock_app_handler():
    # do something
    print('doing something')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('done something')


print(mock_app())
```

But, the code is executing synchronously. I am getting the below result.

```
Mock app called
doing something
done something
Thread spawned
success
```

Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

UPDATE:
I tried setting task.daemon = True. That didn't work either.

Comment: `task = threading.Thread(target=mock_app_handler)` # don't call the function there, instead pass the function object. Also you don't need the `args` there, since the function doesn't take any arguments

Comment: @hansolo Thanks. My bad. Didn't realize it until now. Worked now.

Comment: @hansolo add this as an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: Sure. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, you were calling the function `mock_app_handler` instead of passing the function object. The `target` in [threading.Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) expects a callable. So

Instead of

```
task = threading.Thread(target=mock_app_handler(), args=())
```

Use

```
task = threading.Thread(target=mock_app_handler)
```

Also you don't need to pass the empty `args`, since the function `mock_app_handler` doesn't need any `args`.

Comment: My code is a stripped-down version of the actual code. The actual code has args to be passed. Thanks.